# Using edittext output as a output filename

Tags: android, android-edittext, output, sensors

I am totaly new to java and android programming.
I wrote simple program to collect data from some sensors and save them in .TXT file.
I am using 2 services and main activity.
I need help which part where I added editText.
I want to specify output filename to something.txt. (name should be output from edittext)

Can you help me with this? I need advice how to do it...

Comment: can you please be a bit more clear on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How I should use edittext in relative layout main activity and save output to srting... Then use string in service...

Answer (score 0):

you can use sth like this :

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextId);

File file = new File("data/data/your package name/"+editText.getText().toString()+".txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: I am using it but it does not work in service and when i put it in main it gives me error.. Can I use string created in main , in my services when it is public ? I am totally new but i need this to school so be patient pls :D Thanks :D